Need help verifying data provided by google/machine-learning course
In the gradient descent page on the intro to machine-learning course provided by google provided are features and corresponding labels, MSE loss function, initial datasets, and results. I am having difficulty verifying the results that they have and I am wondering if anyone can assist in confirming whether or not I am making a mistake or they are.
I have the following:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [3.5, 18], [3.69, 15], [3.44, 18], [3.43, 16], [4.34, 15], [4.42, 14], [2.37, 24]
initial_data_df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['pounds','mpg'])

number_of_iterations = 6
weight = 0 # initialize weights
bias = 0 # initialize weights
weight_slope = 0
bias_slope = 0
final_results_df = pd.DataFrame()
learning_rate = 0.01

for i in range(number_of_iterations):
    loss = calculate_loss(initial_data_df,weight,bias)
    final_results_df = update_results(final_results_df,weight,bias,loss)
    weight_slope = find_weight_slope(initial_data_df,weight,bias)
    bias_slope = find_bias_slope(initial_data_df,weight,bias)
    weight = new_weight_update(weight,learning_rate,weight_slope)
    bias = new_bias_update(bias,learning_rate,bias_slope)
print(final_results_df)

def calculate_loss(df,weight,bias):
    loss_summation = []
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        loss_summation.append((df['mpg'][i]-((weight*df['pounds'][i])+bias))**2)
    return (sum(loss_summation)//len(df))

def update_results(df,weight,bias,loss):
    if df.empty:
        df = pd.DataFrame([[weight,bias,loss]],columns=['weight','bias','loss'])
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([[weight,bias,loss]],columns=df.columns)])
    return df

def find_weight_slope(df,weight,bias):
    weight_update_summation = []
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        wx_plus_b = (weight*df['pounds'][i])+bias
        wx_plus_b_minus_y = wx_plus_b-df['mpg'][i]
        weight_update_summation.append(2*(wx_plus_b_minus_y*df['pounds'][i]))
    return sum(weight_update_summation)//len(df)

def find_bias_slope(df,weight,bias):
    bias_update_summation = []
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        wx_plus_b = (weight*df['pounds'][i])+bias
        wx_plus_b_minus_y = wx_plus_b-df['mpg'][i]
        bias_update_summation.append(2*wx_plus_b_minus_y)
    total_sum = sum(bias_update_summation)
    return total_sum//len(df)

def new_weight_update(old_weight,lr,slope):
    return old_weight-1*lr*slope

def new_bias_update(old_bias,lr,slope):
    return old_bias-1*lr*slope

Which yields:
iter weight  bias   loss
0    0.00    0.00   303.0
0    1.20    0.35   170.0
0    2.06    0.60   102.0
0    2.67    0.79   67.0
0    3.10    0.93   50.0
0    3.41    1.04   41.0

This differs from the provided solution provided on the website:
Iteration   Weight  Bias    Loss (MSE)
1           0       0       303.71
2           1.2     0.34    170.67
3           2.75    0.59    67.3
4           3.17    0.72    50.63
5           3.47    0.82    42.1
6           3.68    0.9     37.74


So I made some minor adjustments to my script based on the feedback from the AI chat bot provided by google. See below:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():
    data = [3.5, 18], [3.69, 15], [3.44, 18], [3.43, 16], [4.34, 15], [4.42, 14], [2.37, 24]
    initial_data_df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['pounds','mpg'])

    number_of_iterations = 6
    weight = 0 # initialize weights
    bias = 0 # initialize weights
    weight_slope = 0
    bias_slope = 0
    final_results_df = pd.DataFrame()
    learning_rate = 0.01

    for i in range(number_of_iterations):
        loss = round(calculate_loss(initial_data_df,weight,bias),2)
        final_results_df = update_results(final_results_df,weight,bias,loss)
        weight_slope = find_weight_slope(initial_data_df,weight,bias)
        bias_slope = find_bias_slope(initial_data_df,weight,bias)
        weight = round(new_weight_update(weight,learning_rate,weight_slope),2)
        bias = round(new_bias_update(bias,learning_rate,bias_slope),2)
    print(final_results_df)

def calculate_loss(df,weight,bias):
    loss_summation = []
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        loss_summation.append((df['mpg'][i]-((weight*df['pounds'][i])+bias))**2)
    return (sum(loss_summation)/len(df))

def update_results(df,weight,bias,loss):
    if df.empty:
        df = pd.DataFrame([[weight,bias,loss]],columns=['weight','bias','loss'])
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([[weight,bias,loss]],columns=df.columns)])
    return df

def find_weight_slope(df,weight,bias):
    slope = []
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        predicted_mpg = (weight*df['pounds'][i])+bias   #   predicted_mpg = (weight * car_weight) + bias
        error = predicted_mpg-df['mpg'][i]
        slope.append(error*2*df['pounds'][i])
    return sum(slope)/len(df)

def find_bias_slope(df,weight,bias):
    slope = []
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        predicted_mpg = (weight*df['pounds'][i])+bias   #   predicted_mpg = (weight * car_weight) + bias
        error = predicted_mpg-df['mpg'][i]
        slope.append(2*error)
    return sum(slope)/len(df)

def new_weight_update(old_weight,lr,slope):
    return old_weight-(lr*slope)

def new_bias_update(old_bias,lr,slope):
    return old_bias-(lr*slope)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

With these changes I get the following results:
   weight  bias    loss
0    0.00  0.00  303.71
0    1.20  0.34  170.67
0    2.05  0.59  103.22
0    2.66  0.77   68.66
0    3.09  0.91   51.13
0    3.40  1.01   42.11

I provided the calculated weighted slope to get the next updated weight which should be the third iteration weight value.

With these results and documentation I would conclude that google's example results are incorrect for gradient descent.

Maybe you are not implementing the MSE cost function correctly, or you're initializing the hyperparameters (like learning rate) with other values, but look the MSE results on both: your answer and the result provided by google website, they're decreasing in each iteration, that doesn't mean that the algorithm is learning??
